# TypeScript: How to insert a multidimensional array into another multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, multidimensional-array

A two-dimensional array is to be **extended** (No new one is to be created):

```
let array:number[][] = [
    [5, 6],
];
```

For this we have two more two-dimensional arrays `a1` and `a2`:

```
let a1:number[][] = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
let a2:number[][] = [[7, 8], [9, 10]];
```

The goal is now to insert `a1` at the beginning and `a2` at the end of `array`:

```
array.unshift(a1);
array.push(a2);
```

The syntax is not permitted and the following errors occur:

```
Argument of type 'number[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

The expected result is as follows:

```
[
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8],
    [9, 10]
];
```

Does TypeScript/Javascript provide a way to insert the arrays without having to iterate and unshift/push element by element?

**Please not:**
Since the existing array can become very large, I would like to avoid copies (e.g. by concat or something similar).

Comment: Unpack it...`array.unshift(...a1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You just need to use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
let array: number[][] = [[5, 6]];

let a1: number[][] = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
];
let a2: number[][] = [
  [7, 8],
  [9, 10],
];

array.unshift(...a1);
array.push(...a2);

console.log(array);
// [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/DYUwLgBAhgTjUE8BcEB2BXAtgIxDA2gLpEQC8E++ArADQQBshhA3AFCuiRQCMKGOeIiXL5WECtzoAmQjTEUAzHQAss1iw7hoUvllwFihMhXn4A7HQAca8fgCcdbgAY1G1rHgIAdOlQBnAAsASwAzMAAKLyieAEo2D0QvAAd0QMjoqTj2AGMAe39c0C9gXIBzcISELIB6aop8SQgZOnwlCFUW2gZZCgsIaxaHCGcmCCA)

Answer (score 1):

why not sort the array after adding new element using `array.sort`

```js
let array = [
    [5, 6],
];

let a2 = [[1, 2], [3, 4]];
let a1 = [[7, 8], [9, 10]];

array.unshift(...a1);
array.push(...a2);

array = array.sort((a, b) => a[0]-b[0])
console.log(array);
```

Comment: What is the sorting used for? I would like to avoid unnecessary actions if they are not absolutely necessary.

Comment: because is this sample we know the content of array but if we invert a1 and a2 the result will not be the same with a sort you will be sure that whatever contain a1 and a2 the result will be always the same. I edit my reply to show you